# xPath query problem

Tags: php, dom, xpath

In a previous question, user helped me but i'm stuck of doing simple request :

```
<?php $nodes = $xPath->query('//table[@class="some_class"]');
```

But it returns me the whole table datas instead of rows of the table, that's why i want to retrive only "td" of the table.

I tryed (but **it's not working**)

```
 <?php $nodes = $xPath->query('//table[@class="some_class"]/tbody/tr');
```

What am I doing wrong please ?

**EDIT HTML structure **

```
<table class="some_class">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="firstcol" width="160">name</td>
<td width="250">Some&nbsp;Data</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML you are using, so we can get an idea of the exact structure.

Comment: Without input sample, only guessing... `//table[@class="some_class"]//td`

Comment: please also make sure there is just `some_class` and not `some_class` and `some_other_class` in class attribute. You will have to use the `contains` function otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//table[@class='some_class']//td
```

Added a middle `//` in there because of my mistrust at any level of `tbody`'s actually being there (although for DOM they should be).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the path matches correctly, you may just need to append /* to match all child nodes:

`//table[@class="some_class"]/tbody/tr/*`

Comment: arg, not working, i updated my post with additional information. thanks

Comment: @Tristan - "not working" should be a red flag saying "how do you know it's not working? Share that info." E.g. what value is $xPath->query() returning?

Comment: I suspect that _if_ it's not working, it is because the OP used something like firebug / another DOM HTML presentation tool to look at HTML, which showed a `<tbody>`, but is using the source of a page, in which the `<tbody>` isn't present...

Comment: no return, no data displayed i meant :°). Thanks Wrikken, it may be the cause :)

Comment: If it's the same http://www.esl.eu/fr/player/5178309/ again, there is indeed no `<tbody>`

Comment: yeap, thanks was looking with firebug the html structure. :')